# Rotation operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

The problem is this: Consider the operator  $e^{-\frac{i\pi L_y}{2\hbar}}$. If you apply it to an eigenstate of $L^2$ and $L_x$ with $l = 1$, prove that the resulting state is an eigenstate of $L_z$.

The idea is this:
$$L_z\left ( e^{-\frac{i\pi L_y}{2\hbar}}Y_{1,m} \right )=-i\hbar \frac{\partial }{\partial \varphi }\left ( e^{-\frac{i\pi L_y}{2\hbar}}Y_{1,m} \right )=...=2\hbar ^2\left (e^{-\frac{i\pi L_y} {2\hbar}}Y_{1,m} \right ).$$

But I don't know how to move from one equation to the other. I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked (carefully) at the raising and lowering operators, what they are composed of and how they commute with $L^2$? It's been a while since  I did this stuff,  so I don't want to lead you the wrong way, sorry if I do, (but you will still learn :),  but also read http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qm/lectures/node38.html

Answer (score 2):

Absorb $\hbar$ into your definitions of *L*, etc. 
An eigenstate of $L^2$ with eigenvalue 2=1(1+1) is a vector representation 
of the rotation group, so, then [3×3 matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations).

An *R(π/2)* rotation around the *y*-axis lowers the *z* axis to the *x* axis, so 
$$
e^{i\pi L_y/2} L_z e^{-i\pi L_y/2}= -L_x ~.
$$
(Could prove it from Rodrigues rotation formula, or, more directly, from
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 0 &  1\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
- 1 & 0 &  0 
\end{bmatrix}   
 \begin{bmatrix}
 0 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
 1 &    0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 &  0\\
\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 0 &  -1\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 &  0 \\
\end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 &  0 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  1  & 0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}  
$$ in the WP article cited above, with real antisymmetric generators instead of complex hermitian ones.)

You thus consider an eigenstate $|\psi\rangle$ of $L_x$ with eigenvalue *c*, and 
$$
L_z ~ e^{-i\pi L_y/2} |\psi\rangle = e^{-i\pi L_y/2}  e^{i\pi L_y/2} L_z e^{-i\pi L_y/2}  |\psi\rangle   = - e^{-i\pi L_y/2} L_x  |\psi\rangle = -c  e^{-i\pi L_y/2} |\psi\rangle ~,
$$
as mandated.

- (Your stated idea for a proof is off the mark. Spherical harmonics are not eigenstates of $L_x$.The point of the question is to relate eigenspaces of $L_x$ to those of $L_y$.)
- A gratuitous teaching moment aside, which you may choose to ignore. Many grownups would produce the Lie-algebraic relation, $e^{i\pi L_y/2} L_z e^{-i\pi L_y/2}=- L_x$, directly in the faithful doublet representation, Pauli matrices, ***σ***/2. In the doublet, however, it is trivial, $\frac{1}{2} (1+i\sigma_y)\sigma_z (1-i\sigma_y)= -\sigma_x  $. But such a Lie-algebraic identity holds for *all* representations if it holds in *some* faithful representation, so it would also hold in the triplet rep you are interested in.