# Queries about rotation in QM for spin $s = 1$ system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, hilbert-space, quantum-spin, rotation

I am interested in how to do a rotation about the $x$-axis in QM for spin $s = 1$ system. In an answer to [the post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/41697/what-is-the-spin-rotation-operator-for-spin-1-2?rq=1) we have that for a general rotation in QM where spin $s = 1$ we have the equation:
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
  \exp(i\alpha \mathbf{J}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}}) & = 1 + i\hat{\mathbf{n}}\cdot\mathbf{J}\sin\alpha + (\hat{\mathbf{n}}\cdot\mathbf{J})^2(\cos\alpha-1) \\
& = 1 + \left[2i\hat{\mathbf{n}}\cdot\mathbf{J}\sin(\alpha/2)\right]\cos(\alpha/2) + \frac{1}{2}\left[2i\hat{\mathbf{n}}\cdot\mathbf{J}\sin(\alpha/2)\right]^2,
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
**Questions:**
Should the LHS not be $\exp(i\alpha \mathbf{J}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}}/2)$ as in the $s = 1/2$ case, where we have $$\exp(-i\frac{\alpha}{2}\vec{\sigma}\cdot\textbf{n}) = \cos\biggl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\biggr)-i\vec{\sigma}\cdot\textbf{n}\sin\biggl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\biggr)?$$ Also, would the idea be to then be to write $J_x = J_{+}+J_{-}$ where we have the raising and lowering operators, and then to express this as a matrix in the basis of $J_z$ eigenstates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  When writing $\exp(i\alpha \hat n\cdot \vec J)$ one must use matrices $\hat J_x,\hat J_y,\hat J_z$ with the standard commutation relations:
$$
[\hat J_x,\hat J_y]=i\hbar \hat J_z\, , \hbox{etc}
$$
For $s=1/2$, the matrices that satisfy the commutation relations are 
$\{\textstyle\frac{1}{2}\sigma_x,\textstyle\frac{1}{2}\sigma_y,\textstyle\frac{1}{2}\sigma_z\}$ rather than
$\{\sigma_x,\sigma_y,\sigma_z\}$, hence the need for the $\textstyle\frac{1}{2}$ factor.

Yes in general one would obtain the matrices for $\hat J_x$ and $\hat J_y$, lump them with $\hat J_z$ to construct 
$\exp(i\alpha \hat n\cdot \vec J)$ and exponentiate.  The result does not depend on the basis but the basis of eigenstates of $\hat J_z$ is convenient since the $\hat J_\pm$ in this basis are well known and easy to compute.

---

Edit: in answer to a comment, the rotation matrices are usually of the form 
$$
R_z(\alpha)R_y(\beta)R_z(\gamma)=e^{-i \alpha L_z}e^{-i\beta Ly}
e^{-i\gamma L_z}
$$
To get $R_x$ one should choose $\alpha=-\pi/2$ and $\gamma=\pi/2$.

In a basis of eigenstates of $\hat J_z$, the rotation 
$R_x(\beta)=e^{i \pi L_z/2} R_y(\beta) e^{-i\pi L_z/2}$ for $s=1/2$ is given by 
$$
R_x(\beta)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \cos \left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right) & -i \sin \left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right) \\
 -i \sin \left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right) & \cos \left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)=e^{-i\beta \sigma_x/2}\, ,
$$
with states ordered as $\vert 1/2,1/2\rangle,\vert 1/2,-1/2\rangle$.

For $\ell=1$ the corresponding result is
$$
R_x(\beta)=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \cos ^2\left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right) & -\frac{i \sin (\beta )}{\sqrt{2}} & -\sin ^2\left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right) \\
 -\frac{i \sin (\beta )}{\sqrt{2}} & \cos (\beta ) & -\frac{i \sin (\beta )}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 -\sin ^2\left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right) & -\frac{i \sin (\beta )}{\sqrt{2}} & \cos ^2\left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
for the ordering $\vert 1,1\rangle, \vert 1,0\rangle, \vert 1,-1\rangle$

Comment: Are the signs for the above terms correct? It seems that he made a mistake that the second term is '+' for the $s = \frac{1}{2}$ case where it should be '-'.

Comment: Can I ask your advice about something. I have a python code which I wrote using that formula to calculate the rotation of a state $|s = 1; J_z \rangle$ about the $x$ axis. I have another code which does the same thing but gives a different answer, but the difference is that the signs and the order of components are different (the numbers are the same). So it's like one of them is a permutation of the other with a sign difference at times for the components. I am using $J_x = \frac{1}{2}J_{+} + \frac{1}{2}J_{-}$.

Comment: Thanks that is quite useful, been doing that by hand...for a while... For the last matrix, are you sure you don't get $i\frac{sin(\beta)}{\sqrt{2}}$ (without the negative sign that you have)?

Comment: That is correct, I get that as well, but then you just multiply by $i \sin(\beta)$. There's no negative sign. Oh I think it's because you are using a negative argument for exponential.

Comment: Could just confirm that this is correct for rotation about $z$ axis  $$R_{z}(\alpha) =\begin{bmatrix}
    i\sin \alpha + cos \alpha & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
    0 & 0 & i\sin \alpha + cos \alpha 
\end{bmatrix}$$?

Comment: One last thing. What I am interested in doing, is considering the state $|J=1, M=1\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}
    1  \\
    0  \\
    0  
\end{bmatrix}$, forming the coherent state $|CS \rangle = \begin{bmatrix}
    0.5  \\
    -\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}  \\
    -0.5  
\end{bmatrix}$ by taking the rotation $\text{exp}(\frac{-i\pi}{2}J_x)\begin{bmatrix}
    1  \\
    0  \\
    0  
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    0.5  \\
    -\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}  \\
    -0.5  
\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Then I want to work out the modulus squared of the overlap of the coherent state with a rotation of the coherent state about the $x$-axis and the $z$-axis for various values of $\theta$ and $\phi$: $|\langle CS| \text{exp}(-i \phi J_z) \text{exp}(-i \theta J_x)|CS\rangle|^2$. The result I get is [this plot](http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4211/34692246053_e0fd2d7cd8_b.jpg). Is this the type of plot you would have predicted? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JohnJack this looks ok.

Comment: Thanks for checking, would you not have expected a more circular symmetric shape? If you take level curves of this, it looks like you would get ellipse type slices. This is my main concern. I have plotted for a very large number of points, hence I don't think it is due to  a lack of points of $\theta$ and $\phi$. What do you think?

Comment: @JohnJack The scale on axes is different.  If you use $0\le\theta\le \pi$ and $0\le\phi\le 2\Pi$ this should help with the symmetry.

Comment: Thanks, but what do you mean by 'the scale on axes is different' and how did you come to that suggestion for the range of $\theta$ and $\phi$